# .htaccess 301 redirect match

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to get all urls of a particular format to 301 redirect to an alternative URL. I have found what I expected would work, and there doesn't seem to be alot of other operations to do the job, but this one seems to break down at the query string.

What I have at the moment is this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/catalogue/index\.php(.*)c=11(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/walking/
```

Here are a few examples of the sort of urls I am trying to redirect:

```
/catalogue/index.php?x=12&c=11&y=19
/catalogue/index.php?c=11&y=19
/catalogue/index.php?c=11
```

Any feedback on this is very welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write this in your .htaccess-file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} c=11
RewriteRule ^catalogue/index\.php$ http://www.domain.com/walking? [NC,L,R=301]
```

Every request to catalogue/index.php containing "c=11" in the query will be redirected.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, that worked. But do you know how to stop it send the query string? So it would go to www.domain.com/walking/ instead of www.domain.com/walking/?c=11

Comment: Nevermind! It turns out you did, I was just a numpty and deleted the question mark at the end. All sorted, thanks again Christopher!